# How can you make the checkbox in Google Spreadsheet sort specific data? Is the script function necessary?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, checkbox, google-sheets, scripting

I would like to know if there is a way to sort some data based on the checkbox in Google Spreadsheet. Is there any specific function which can sort based on if statement or script needs to be created?

[image]

Each group has a Group Done and checkbox for it below it. The idea is to once you press the checkbox, it would sort out the group based on P (Position). Not sure exactly how to create it.

If the script is needed I was already doing once automatic sorting with onEdit() function, but it was a simple one for just one table or one set of Data. Is it possible to do it based on the reference value of the TRUE statement in the sheet and if it finds it, create the box of values from that position and sort it out?

Comment: Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet and explanation about it? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: As a matter of interest, what happens if you "uncheck" the checkbox?

Comment: basically you need simple sorting script for every range conditioned via checkbox

Comment: Are the lists below the checkboxes of a fixed size?